# Default Documents folder still being use even though changed

Tags: windows-10, documents

"Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders\Personal" has been changed to "D:\Users[user]\OneDrive\Documents", so has the "Documents Properties" and all works well, even OneDrive is correctly syncing. However some programs (including Unreal Engine) is still using "C:\Users[user]\Documents"

Is there any way to fix this or has Epic and otehrs just hard-coded the location instead of using correct standards for Windows?

Edit: Also when starting CMD it defaults to "C:\Users[user]\Documents" instead of the correct D: version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Created a junction using "junction64.exe" v1.07 from Microsoft. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/downloads/junction

In elevated command prompt I used the following commands:

```
del "C:\Users[user]\Documents"
junction64 "C:\Users[user]\Documents" "D:\Users[user]\OneDrive\Documents"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit the values under:

```
Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders
```

In addition to the value named '**Personal**', if a value named '**{f42ee2d3-909f-4907-8871-4c22fc0bf756}**' exists, set that to your desired '**Documents**' path as well.

For the Command Prompt, you need to edit the properties of the shortcut that launch Command Prompt.

1. In the Explorer Address bar, type: `shell:programs`
2. Open the **Windows System** folder
3. Right-click **Command Prompt** & select **Properties**
4. Edit the **Start in:** value (or the underlying environmental variables)

Comment: Oh very interesting about the Windows System! %HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%, So it's defaulting not to my documents but to my user point which of course will still be on c

Comment: Oh, also this doesn't solve the other problems unfortunately. Some developers seem to use the %HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH% method to find the documents folder instead of the correct API. So the redirect in the other answer seems the only way to permi solve the problem. However there's a side effect that you'll see things twice in some programs as they think it's in two places....